# How to inhib special chars of a string to use it as a jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery

Consider the following example :

```
<input type="text" id="#ab>cd.ef" value="foo" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  var id = '#ab>cd.ef';
  alert($('#' + id).length);
</script>
```

This results in a syntax error, so I am looking for something to inhib the special chars of a selector.

Of course, for this single example, I can do :

```
alert($('input').length);
```

But I will use this principle to use dynamic selectors like :

```
return $('input[name="' + $(elem).attr('name') + '"]:checked').val();
```

Even if my "name" attribute contains special chars.

So here is my question : How to inhib special chars of a string to use it as a jQuery selector ?

Comment: I doubt if your element ID is valid.

Comment: This does not respect any doctype, I agree. But javascript does support it (actually, I was doing `$(document.getElementById(id))` which work but is not nice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, enclosed id in single quote and check in attribute selector

```
var id = '#ab>cd.ef';
alert($("[id='"+id+"']").length);
```